# take charge/control of

Tags: parsing

> She was chosen to take charge/control of the organization.

---

Do native speakers think that "take charge/control" is a verb and that "of" is a preposition and that "the organization" is the object of "of".
Or instead do they think that "take" is a verb and that "charge/control of the organization" is the object of "take"?

Comment: Obviously *whatever* comes immediately after *[Subject] was chosen to...* must be a verb. *She was chosen to **take charge / take control*** can optionally be followed by a prepositional element *(**of** the company)*, but it doesn't *have* to be. OR you could have a transitive verb that doesn't need a preposition before its object: *She was chosen to **run the company***.

Comment: (***take charge / take control / take over / take part / take advantage / take care / ...*** are "phrasal verbs". It's not necessarily helpful to try and analyze the ***take*** part separately. They're not like ***Take a card, Take a holiday, Take the biscuit***, where what follows ***take*** is meaningfully an "object".)

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I upvoted your comment. But at the same time, I wonder if *take control* is a bit different from the others you enumerate. It’s the only one that can be made more dramatic—perhaps more violent—by swapping out *take* for *seize*.  But I can think of nothing else that would suggest that *take **control*** is special.

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum: I can't see that "take control" is somehow different because it can be made "more dramatic". What about, say, "take **command**" or "take **possession**"? They could certainly imply "amid dramatic violence". Anyway, the point is the OP here is *specifically* asking whether native speakers "unpack" these phrasal verbs as consisting of the verb ***take*** plus "something taken" (like you might *take **a biscuit*** from the plate). ***Of course we don't!*** If someone said *I take offense at what you said*, we don't wonder where he's gonna put the offense he just relieved me of!

Comment: @FumbleFingers, oh I quite agree my thought was off the subject of the OP.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: We aren't talking about a verb phrase, but a phrasal verb. This is a distinct thing from a verb phrase. "Take command" isn't a literal physical taking of something, but it is still "taking" something. (The person who took command now *has* that command, though they can't put it on their desk) "Take offense" is an idiom, not a phrasal verb.

Comment: The components of a phrasal verb are almost always a particle and/or a preposition. Command, which is a noun here, is just an object.

Comment: @Kaia: That's all a matter of formal syntax and terminology. The OP here seems to be asking whether a native speaker (such as myself) thinks in terms of ***take*** being "a verb" in ***take charge*** and similar. And personally, I don't.

Comment: @FumbleFingers (***take charge / take control / take over / take part / take advantage / take care / ...*** are "phrasal verbs". It's not necessarily helpful to try and analyze the ***take*** part separately.) Likewise, in "**in control of**..." and "**in the mood for**...", do you not see "**control of**..." and "**the mood for**..." as the object of "**in**"s?

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with the comments. "Take" is the verb, and "charge of the organization" is the object.

The typical test for a phrasal verb is checking whether you can add an adjective or adverb between the two words. Using FumbleFinger's examples:

- She takes **full** charge of the organization.
- She takes **partial** control of the organization.
- She takes **no** part in the plan.
- She takes **full** advantage of the situation.
- She takes **due** care to avoid the dangers.

Because we can split the phrase, these examples are not phrasal verbs. "Take" is the verb and the remainder of the sentence is the object. In contrast, a phrasal verb cannot be split like this. The following sentences sound unnatural when you try to insert a word between them:

- She **takes on** an apprentice. (Incorrect: She takes quickly on an apprentice.)
- She **takes out** her phone. (Incorrect: She takes quickly out her phone.)
- She **takes over** the company. (Incorrect: She takes fully over the company.)